# How to call the combined set of training, test and validation data

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, supervised-learning

If I want to refer to the whole set of preprocessed data samples ready to be split into training-, validation- and test-set, how should I call it?

Comment: simply "the full sample"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a specific name for it; when writing I usually call it "processed dataset", or simply "model inputs".